# Laplace method on a simplex with factorized integrand

Tags: simplex, laplace-method

I need to obtain an approximation to an integral of the form:

$$I = \int_0^1 \mathrm e^{M \sum_i f_i(x_i)} \mathrm \delta\left(\sum_i x_i - 1\right) d\mathbf x$$

where $M$ is a large real number. Here the functions $f_1(x_1), f_2(x_2), \dots, f_N(x_N)$ are $N$ real functions, sufficiently smooth.

I suspect I can apply a variant of the [Laplace method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), but I am not sure how to proceed due to the presence of the Dirac delta. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

**Note:** See [Laplace method on a simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2899447/10063) for a more general version of this problem, where the integrand is not factorized.

Comment: If we perform the $x_n$ integral then it reduces to $\int e^{MF(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})}{\rm d}x_1\cdots{\rm d}x_{n-1}$ where the integrand is $F = \sum f_i(x_i)$ with $x_n\to 1-x_1-\ldots-x_{n-1}$ so this introduces mixing between the coordinates so the integral is no longer factorizable. But you can apply (a multidimensional) Laplace method to this one given you can compute the critical points.

Comment: @Winther Do you mind taking a look at the answer I posted? I did a Fourier transform first and then a Laplace approximation. This way there is no coupling. But I am not 100% sure that this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, only my attempt to solve the problem.

Let $F_k(v)$ be the Fourier transform of $\mathrm e^{M f_k(x_k)}$, restricted to $[0,1]$,

$$F_k(v)=\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi\mathrm{i}x_k v_k + Mf_k(x_k)}\mathrm{d}x_k  \qquad (1)$$

By the convolution theorem

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{k}F_{k}\left(v\right)\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}v}\mathrm{d}v$$

So far so good. To approximate $F_k(v)$, I would like to try to use the Laplace method. I'm not sure about the correctness of this approach here, but let's move forward. We make a second-order Taylor expansion:

$$f_k(x_k) \approx f_k(x_k^*) + \frac{1}{2} f_k^{''}(x_k^*)(x_k-x_k^*)^2$$

Assume that $0<x_k^*<1$ and $f_k^{''}(x_k)<0$. In the limit $M\rightarrow\infty$ we can approximate:

$$\begin{aligned}
F_k(v_k) &\approx \mathrm{e}^{M f_k(x_k^*)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi\mathrm{i} x_k v_k + \frac{M}{2} f_k^{''}(x_k^*)(x_k-x_k^*)^2}\mathrm{d}x_{k} \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{M |f_k^{''}(x_k^*)|}} \exp\left(-2\pi\mathrm{i}x_k^*v+Mf_k(x_k^*)+\frac{2\pi^2v^2}{Mf_k^{''}(x_k^*)}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Hence

$$\begin{aligned}
I &\approx \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{M\prod_{s}\left|f_{s}^{\prime\prime}\left(x_{s}^{*}\right)\right|}}\mathrm{e}^{M\sum_{s}f_{s}\left(x_{s}^{*}\right)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left\{ -2\pi\mathrm{i}v\left(\sum_k x_k^*-1\right)+\frac{2\pi^{2}v^{2}}{M}\sum_k\frac{1}{f_k^{''}(x_k^*)}\right\} \mathrm{d}v \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\prod_k|f_k^{''}(x_k^*)|\right)\left(\sum_k\frac{1}{|f_k^{''}(x_k^*)|}\right)}}\exp\left\{ M\sum_kf_k(x_k^*)+\frac{M}{2} \frac{\left(\sum_k x_k^*-1\right)^2}{\sum_k\frac{1}{f_k^{''}(x_k^*)}}\right\} 
\end{aligned}$$

**The problem** with this "solution" is that I'm not sure if it is right. How can I check?

Comment: You have a bit of a collision between $i$ the index and $i$ the imaginary unit. In any case the imaginary term doesn't create any problem, you can think of the exponential part as just a $\Theta(1)$ multiplicative factor.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. I went forward with the Laplace method. Is there a way I can check this approximation to see if it really works? Maybe some special functions $f$ for which an exact answer can be given so I can compare?

Comment: To check it try to compare it to a simple case you can do analytically (or get the asymptotics using software like Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha). For example $\int_0^1 e^{M(x^2+y^2)}\delta(x+y-1){\rm d}x{\rm d}y \sim \frac{e^M}{M}$ for large $M$ might be useful. The case $x^3 + y^3$ is also solvable and is $\sim \frac{2e^M}{3M}$ for large $M$.

Comment: @Winther I am worried about the final integration w.r.t. $v$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Actually I now suspect that this approach is wrong. But I cannot see why. Is there a way to prove it (or not)?

Comment: Did you try a simple test case and compared the results?

Comment: @Winther Yes. I tried $f_i(x_i)=(x_i-1/2)$ (to move the maximum of $f_i$ to the interior of $[0,1]$, although this is probably not essential). With Mathematica I find that the exact integral (for $N=2$) goes like $4e^{M/2}/M^2$. However with this formula you get $e^0$ times some constant factors, *i.e.*, no exponential growth!

Comment: I think there is an implicit exchange of limits here. I should take $v\rightarrow\infty$ first (when doing the last Fourier integral) and then $M\rightarrow\infty$, but I am taking them in the wrong order and this is not justified.

Comment: I haven't looked at your derivation, it's too much work. But I suspect that you don't take into account the oscillatory nature of the integrand ($e^{i x_k v_k}$) and this is what's the problem. What I can say is this: isf simple test cases don't work then it's just not correct.